# How to display multiple query in one line for Odoo Qweb Report

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, qweb

I am making a report from `sale.order.line`. Here I want to display the `product_id.product_tmpl_id.name` `product_id.code`, `sum(product_oum_qty)` in last month, `sum(price_unit)` in last month, `sum(product_oum_qty)` in last year, `sum(price_unit)` in last year, etc. from the order lines and grouped by `product_id`, but I don't know how to do it.

Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28UCg.png) of my current report:

This code only generates the data by date selected from the wizard. And I repeated the quantity and amount data just to show as an example.

```
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
    super(orderline_lists, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
    self.localcontext.update({
        'show_orderlines':self._orderline_details,
    })

def _orderline_details(self, form):
    data = []
    result = {}
    user = self.pool['res.users'].browse(self.cr, self.uid, self.uid)
    tz_name = user.tz or self.localcontext.get('tz') or 'UTC'
    user_tz = pytz.timezone(tz_name)
    between_dates = {}

    for date_field, delta in {'date_from': {'days': 0}, 'date_to': {'days': 1}}.items():
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(form[date_field] + ' 00:00:00', tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + datetime.timedelta(**delta)
        timestamp = user_tz.localize(timestamp).astimezone(pytz.utc)
        between_dates[date_field] = timestamp.strftime(tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)

    orderline_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order.line')
    orderline_ids = orderline_obj.search(self.cr, self.uid, [('create_date', '>=', between_dates['date_from']),('create_date', '<', between_dates['date_to'])])

    for line in orderline_obj.browse(self.cr, self.uid, orderline_ids, context=self.localcontext):
        result = {
            'code': line.product_id.code,
            'description': line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.name,
            # product brand
            'current_qty': line.product_uom_qty,
            'current_amt': line.price_unit,
            'last_mos_qty': line.product_uom_qty,
            'last_mos_amt': line.price_unit,
            'last_yr_qty': line.product_uom_qty,
            'last_yr_amt': line.price_unit,
            'last_3mos_qty': line.product_uom_qty,
            'last_3mos_amt': line.price_unit,
            'last_12mos_qty': line.product_uom_qty,
            'last_12mos_amt': line.price_unit,
        }
        data.append(result)

    if data:
        return data
    else:
        return {}
```

And then i looped it in my qweb view through `show_orderlines` context. Please help :))